# Dynamically Creating Communicators

Tags: mpi, mpich

I have a small communication problem that has consumed hours of search. I am using MPICH2 to communicate between different workers. At some points in my program a process needs to multi-cast a message to a fraction of the workers (2 or 3 out of a total of 20). Therefore, I temporarily need to create a group that includes the ranks of all those workers and then use MPI_BCast. However, this seems to be impossible!

I have tried MPI_Comm_Create but the program simply hangs because it required "every" worker call MPI_Comm_Create. I can not also use MPI_Comm_Split because **I do not know the ranks** of the recipient workers in advance and hence can not color code them.

Could you please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MPI\_Comm\_Create hanging without response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269077/mpi-comm-create-hanging-without-response)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to create a new communicator at all?

Your description, of what you actually want to achieve and what the constraints are is a little lacking, but here are some hints, that might be applicable for your problem.

- Sticking to classical two-sided communication, you need at some point a communication that involves all processes to identify the recipients, I guess. You could for example broadcast to everybody who is to be a recipient, and subsequently send the actual message to those with peer-to-peer communication (If this relation is going to change over time, I would not bother with creating a new communicator each time).
- You could use MPI's one-sided communication concepts, and simply write messages from the broadcasting rank into dedicated memory areas of the receiving ranks. However, one-sided is often considered somewhat bad and not so good on the performance side.
- With MPI-3 you could make use of an non-blocking barrier: All processes open the barrier, and those, which are not the broadcasting rank start immediately testing for the completion of this barrier, open a non-blocking receive for any source and regularly test for that as well, otherwise they proceed as usual. The broadcasting rank however, starts sending out its  message to the actual recipients and when it completed that, it waits for the non-blocking barrier to complete. Now, all processes will find the barrier to complete, and now they can stop listening for the receives, those who didn't get a message can simply send a message to themselves to properly close the communication and proceed in their computation.